# IntelliJ IDEA cant find JDK directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, linux-mint

I am trying to set up ItelliJ IDEA with JDK 11 on Linux Mint. I can see the jdk exists in the folder `/usr/lib/jvm` however IDEA cannot see this directory in the SDK configure module and returns `Specified path cannot be found`.

proof jvm folder exists

[image]

IDEA not showing multiple folders inside `/usr/lib`

IDEA JDK interface

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Select Home Directory for JDK because IntelliJ can't see it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499133/cant-select-home-directory-for-jdk-because-intellij-cant-see-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the tar.gz distribution from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html#section=linux). Extract it to a location on your system then CD into the bin folder and launch using `./idea.sh`

Comment: Thanks, the issue was apparently that IDEA was installed with Flatpak. Reinstalling with this fixed the issue