# IntelliJ - Can't navigate to JDK directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I can `cd` to the JDK path

```
user@pc:~$ cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
user@pc:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin$
```

But IntelliJ won't let me navigate there

[image]

How to fix?

**Specs**

- Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon x64
- Linux Kernel 5.1.0-050100-generic
- IntelliJ IDEA Community 2019.2
- OpenJDK 8 1.8.0_222 headless

Comment: Have you tried copying the directory path from your and pasted it in the textbox above?

Comment: Did you try `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/` directory instead?

Comment: @FelixFavour Yes. That's what's in the screenshot (excluding `/bin` still doesn't work)

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, no such luck. IntelliJ won't see beyond `/usr/lib`

Comment: Does it help if you enable the [option to show the hidden files and directories](https://i.imgur.com/MYRuIMN.png)? What are the permissions of the JDK home path? Did you install IntelliJ IDEA via `snap`?

Comment: @series0ne ping?

Comment: @CrazyCoder ping...love it XD. I'm not sure what the issue is, nor do I have the OS to test it. I reverted back to Ubuntu.

Comment: It might be caused by the sandbox. Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55965546/94148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check user's privileges which runs IntelliJ